# Create array from some string from text file - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, file

I'm trying to create array from string from text file.

For example in txt file I have string.

```
"ABC;DEF;GHI"
```

I want to create array which looks like:

```
["ABC","DEF","GHI"]
```

I have tried that using method below:

```
File.open(file.txt).map { |line| line.split(/;/) }
```

but output of the above method was:

```
[["ABC","DEF","GHI"]]
```

You may notice that this is an array within an array.

What I should to do?

Comment: You should `flatten` it. https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map

Comment: Thank I tried and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flat_map` instead of `map`

Code

```
File.open(file.txt).flat_map{ |line| line.split(/;/) }
```

Comment: I know but I could not accept earlier because because the answer can be accepted at the earliest 10 min after asking the question

Comment: Ah Okay. I thought you might not be knowing it, sorry!